# If current produces a magnetic field, how can the current be known?

Tags: current

If the flow of electrons (i.e. current) produces a magnetic field, how can the actual flow be calculated? You cannot know if some external magnetism interferes and affects the velocity of the electrons, right?

Comment: See: [the B field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#The_B-field) where it describes how to determine the external magnetic field in such cases.

Comment: But doesn't the possible external magnetic fields make Ohm's law (when calculating the current) inaccurate?

Comment: I have no way of knowing what you are asking, unfortunately. You are asking for a quantitative answer and the only way to give a quantitative answer is to have a quantitative question. The entire context ALWAYS matters. Laws apply where they apply and they don't apply where they don't. You have to know the details to know what to apply and how to apply it. I'll further recommend that you spend time reading Chabay and Sherwood's "Matter & Interactions", 3rd edition or later. It's very intuitive and easy to read and it will set things up so that you can, perhaps, phrase your question precisely.

Comment: Constant magnetic fields have no effect on current flow. Only variable ones do.

Comment: Most of circuit theory is based on the assumption (called the "lumped circuit approximation") that size of the whole circuit is small enough that it doesn't generate any magnetic fields (aside from specified inductors) and it isn't affected by external magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

External magnetic fields can in theory affect the current in a wire. This is well used in transformers. This is because in any place where the magnetic field changes, there's automatically an electric field which affects the motion of electrons. That's the induction.

But if you want to measure magnetically an existing current in a wire (=you want to know what the current is, no matter what fields have caused it) you need to put the wire through a current clamp. The clamp takes into the account only that magnetic field which is circularly around the wire. External fieds do not affect the measurement, altough they can have some effect to the actual current.